# Dynamic value not working in swing swing Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to use the swing Timer class in java. When I'm hard coding the delay, the code is running with the delayed time. In this case 5 seconds

```
Timer timer= new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            System.out.println("running...");
        }   

    });
```

But, when I'm trying to set the delay variable dynamically using a constructor, it's running with a 0 millisecond delay.

```
Timer timer= new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            System.out.println("running...");
        }   

    });
```

Please let me know how i can set the delay dynamically in Timer class.

Entire Code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;


class StartStop implements ActionListener{

    
    JFrame f=new JFrame(); 
    JButton startButton=new JButton("START"); 
    JButton stopButton=new JButton("STOP"); 
    int delay; 
    
    Timer timer= new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
            System.out.println("running...");
        }   
    });

    public StartStop(int interval) {        
        this.delay=interval; // setting the delay variable to 5 seconds
        
        System.out.println(delay);
        startButton.setBounds(50,10,95,30);     
        startButton.setFocusable(false);
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        stopButton.setBounds(200,10,95,30); 
        stopButton.setFocusable(false);
        stopButton.addActionListener(this);

        f.add(startButton);      
        f.add(stopButton);
        
        
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400,100);  
        f.setLayout(null);  
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()==startButton)
        {
            System.out.println("started");
            start();
        }
        
        if(e.getSource()==stopButton)
        {
            System.out.println("stopped");
            stop();
        }

    }

    void start()
    {
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }
    void stop()
    {
        timer.stop();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        StartStop ss=new StartStop(5000); //passing a 5 second delay to constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: `f.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you create a new timer with the delay that doesn't have a value yet, which turns into 0.
You can fix this by adding:

```
void start() {
   timer.setDelay(delay);
   timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Just one minor correction, it's not true that "delay doesn't have a value yet."  It very definitely has a value, and that value is 0.

Comment: @markspace I am well aware and I said it in my answer, however I could've made it a bit clearer. I meant that the delay does not have a value assigned to it, that's why it defaults to 0.

Answer (score 2):

It's 0 because when you create the Timer the value of `delay` is 0.

```
class StartStop implements ActionListener{

    
    JFrame f=new JFrame(); 
    JButton startButton=new JButton("START"); 
    JButton stopButton=new JButton("STOP"); 
    int delay; 
    
    Timer timer;

    public StartStop(int interval) {        
        this.delay=interval; // setting the delay variable to 5 seconds
        
        System.out.println(delay);
        timer= new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
            System.out.println("running...");
          }   
        });
```